# FF+Jenkins: random selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver

OS: Ubuntu 14, FF61, geckodriver 0.21.0, python2.7

My script basically looks like

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = wd.Firefox()
try:
    browser.get(url)
    ui.WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(lambda x: len(x.title) > 1)
except Exception as e:
    print str(e)
    browser.save_screenshot(img_folder + camid + ".png")
    print "get icon type error: " + url
browser.quit()
```

Using Jenkins to trigger several scripts in this style randomly (it is hard to tell what the exactly frequency is), I got exceptions at "browser.save_screenshot" and "browser.quit()" and "browser = wd.Firefox()". To me, it doesn't make any sense, because each one of them can be executed successfully. There must be something went wrong when several scripts run together. These scripts may share same input but never write to same file. Or one script may be triggered twice with different inputs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "orgDaily.py", line 30, in <module>
browser.save_screenshot(img_folder + camid + ".png")
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1031, in save_screenshot
return self.get_screenshot_as_file(filename)
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1008, in 
get_screenshot_as_file
png = self.get_screenshot_as_png()
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1040, in 
get_screenshot_as_png
return base64.b64decode(self.get_screenshot_as_base64().encode('ascii'))
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/sitepackages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1050, in get_screenshot_as_base64
return self.execute(Command.SCREENSHOT)['value']
 File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
```

or

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "orgDaily.py", line 30, in <module>
output = xzharrow.main(query_file,folder)
File "/home/work/baidu/chengxin-qa/monitor/pilu/case/xzhHome/arrow/xzharrow.py", line 94, in main
browser = wd.Firefox()
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 162, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/work/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
```

Comment: Your issue is with the line `browser.save_screenshot(img_folder + camid + ".png")`. How is `img_folder` and `camid` defined?

Comment: I don't think they are related to this issue. Because "img_folder" is just a directory path and "camid" is the search keyword like "https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=camid".